# Issue with a range creating function [VBA

Tags: vba

I have some trouble to know where to look at to debug my prog. So, to explain my problem, I created a function using two strings that returns a range.

```
Function maRange(mois As String, annee As String) As Range

    Dim index_debut As Long
    Dim index_fin As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Sheets("Suivi charge").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To lastRow Step 1
        If Mid(Sheets("Suivi charge").Range("A" & i).Value, 4, 2) = mois And Right(Sheets("Suivi charge").Range("A" & i).Value, 4) = annee Then
            index_debut = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    For j = index_debut To lastRow Step 1
        If Mid(Sheets("Suivi charge").Range("A" & j).Value, 4, 2) <> mois Or Right(Sheets("Suivi charge").Range("A" & j).Value, 4) <> annee Then
            index_fin = j - 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    Set maRange = Range("C" & index_debut & ":D" & index_fin)

End Function
```

Basically, the first string is the month (if I'd like to get all data that has been collected in January, I'll just do : Set variable = maRange("01", "2020"). It work perfectly well by its own.
I created this function to loop and add the data contained in the range created by the maRange function to a chart, in a different collection in order to compare same data but at different periods of time.

```
Dim i As Long
Sheets("Suivi charge").Select
Set tableauCharge = Sheets("Graphique").ChartObjects.Add(Top:=40, Left:=240, Width:=750, Height:=250)

With tableauCharge.Chart
    .ChartType = xlXYScatter
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .HasLegend = False
    .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlTimeScale
    '.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 30
    .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = #1/1/2020#
    .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = #7/1/2020#
    '.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Courbe de suivi de la charge du " & Sheets("Suivi charge").Range("A3") & " au " & Sheets("Suivi charge").Range("A" & lastRow)
End With

For i = 1 To 4
    Set mois2020_i = maRange("0" & i, "2020")
    frmois2020_i = mois2020_i.Rows(1).Row
    lrmois2020_i = mois2020_i.Rows.Count + frmois2020_i - 1
        With tableauCharge.Chart
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(i).XValues = Sheets("Suivi charge").Range("D" & frmois2020_i & ":D" & lrmois2020_i)
            .SeriesCollection(i).Values = Sheets("Suivi charge").Range("C" & frmois2020_i & ":C" & lrmois2020_i)
        End With
Next i
```

For my example, I stopped at i = 4 because whenever I go higher than 4, I get an error. Here is a screenshot with 4 and an another one with the error :
[image: Here is the i = 1 To 4]

[image: error screenshot]

To translate the error message : "The range method of "*global* has failed.

Ask me for any details, thanks for help and excuse me about my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found that the problem was linked to the fact that at some point, I don't have any data so the programm kept on running for nothing. Here is the corrected version :

```
Function maRange(mois As String, annee As String) As Range

    Dim index_debut As Long
    Dim index_fin As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Sheets("Suivi charge").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To lastRow Step 1
        If Mid(Sheets("Suivi charge").Range("A" & i).Text, 4, 2) = mois And Right(Sheets("Suivi charge").Range("A" & i).Text, 4) = annee Then
            index_debut = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    For j = index_debut To lastRow Step 1
        If StrComp(Mid(Sheets("Suivi charge").Range("A" & j).Text, 4, 2), mois) <> 0 Or StrComp(Right(Sheets("Suivi charge").Range("A" & j).Text, 4), annee) <> 0 Then
            index_fin = j - 1
            Exit For
        End If
        If j = lastRow Then
            index_fin = j
        End If
    Next j
    Set maRange = Range("C" & index_debut & ":D" & index_fin)

End Function
```